# Checkout form custom address attribute input renderer "Object Object"

Tags: magento2.3

I have follow https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

and I have this result for my custom address attribute ( this attribute is save in customer account page )
https://gyazo.com/07ab49785c13e1ea106d742396594a35

If I update this field in checkout form, the result is correct ( correct value is showing on input )

Thanks

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: same code as the documentation, just the step 5 I didn't do because no idea how use it.